# Operating system not found. MBR possibly damanged

Tags: windows-7, boot, mbr

I get a *can't find operating system* message when starting my laptop. I was able to boot into the Windows 7 recovery tools loaded onto a USB. Using diskpart, I noticed my partitions show RAW as the file system. I tried using bootrec, but it show no Windows installation. I also tried startup repair and that doesn't work either.

The hardrive itself is fine. I verified it by running Dell's diagnostic tool on startup. I am thinking the MBR is corrupted. How do I fix it?

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: if you cannot do a fixmbr command from the usb loaded W7, then you will have to reinstall the OS.